# Naive Bayes accuracy comparison between R and Spark ML

Tags: r, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, naivebayes, apache-spark-ml

I am comparing accuracy of Naive Bayes Classifier between R and Spark ML and getting following outcome for Continuous and Categorical data sets

Continuous data set
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/breast-cancer-wisconsin.data

Accuracy 
R - 95% 
Spark ML - 89%

Categorical data set

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/car/car.data

Accuracy 
R - 84% 
Spark ML - 75%

I want to use Spark Naive Bayes algorithm in production, please guide me to minimize difference between accuracy of R and Spark ML (I am using OnehotEncoder to convert categorical to double).

Please help me to understand why there is difference in both output

Comment: independent from question but - why would you encode **categorical data** in doubles? Naive bayes is defined **for categorical data**, the continuous approach is actually a generalisation (which requires additional, quite ugly, assumptions), thus you are actually hurting the model with such encoding.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, spark ML follows pipeline framework for training and testing data set, In case of Spark ML NaiveBayes implementation algorithm expects dataframe (spark data frame) with lable and feature as two columns. Here lable is target / class and feature is Vector of doubles.

Comment: So I need to convert all attributes to 0 and 1 representation and then create Vector of converted data set and pass to NB algorithm in Spark ML. If there is some other work around please share with me for calling Spark ML NB algorithm

Comment: are you doing the same in R? I am convinced R handles categorical values just fine

Comment: NO I am not converting categorical data into onehotencoder as spark is expecting